# ActionMailer not sending emails, pass value in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, mailboxer

I'm using mailboxer to send email notifications and if I do this:

```
def mailboxer_email(object)
  return "me@gmail.com"
end
```

It works perfectly, but I'm trying to return the user's email and I tried this:

```
def mailboxer_email(object)
  return "#{User.email}"    
end
```

I get the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<Class:0x0000000402c138>):
```

when I  tried this:

```
def mailboxer_email(object)
  return :email
end
```

the logs read

```
"sent mail to email"
```

I also tried

```
def mailboxer_email(object) 
  return object.email     
end
```

but gives me

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<Message:0x000000039f0530>):
```

Comment: What does the "no success" for `return object.email` look like?

Comment: `NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<Message:0x000000039f0530>): `

Comment: do messages have users?

Comment: you are looking for user email and passing message as object ..is there email in message..?

Comment: yes, the messaging works flawlessly within the app - or wait you mean messages belonging to users?

Comment: if there is any assoication between user and message you can try object.user.email

Comment: in the message there is username, subject, and body of message, could I do something like `user = User.find_by_username...` then return user.email?

Comment: @Mayank let me try that

Comment: @Mayank that didn't work `NoMethodError (undefined method `user' for #<Message:0x00000003a459e0>):`

Comment: I don't have a message model, just user.rb

Comment: ok...than how you have designed your model is user name is in User model?

Comment: yes, username is in User model, I'm using devise

Answer (score 0):

This method solved it, it was just passing email without " : "

```
def mailboxer_email(object)
  return email  # instead of return :email
end
```